# Playing an audio html tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, audio

I am using ASP.NET Webforms with the following ASPX code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvWordsInLessons"
    runat="server"
    AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>

                <img runat="server" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/kpackage.png"  onclick="return PlaySoundDonoV2(this);" data-audio-index='<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>'  />
                <audio
                    class="audio-file"
                    style="display:none;"
                    data-row-index="<%# CType(Container, GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                    src="<%# Eval("VoiceOver") %>"
                    autostart="false">
                </audio>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

which ultimately produces HTML of the following:

```js
        function PlaySoundDonoV2(aSelectedImg) {
            var rowIndex = $(aSelectedImg).attr('data-audio-index');

            var sound = $(".audio-file[data-row-index='" + rowIndex + "']");
            sound.play();

            //Prevent post-back
            return false;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cphContainerWithoutUpdatePanel_gvWordsInLessons" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/kpackage.png" onclick="return PlaySoundDonoV2(this);" data-audio-index="0" /> 
        <audio class="audio-file" style="display:none;" data-row-index="0" src="/Chinese/words/begin.mp3"
        autostart="false"></audio></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/kpackage.png" onclick="return PlaySoundDonoV2(this);" data-audio-index="1" /> 
        <audio class="audio-file" style="display:none;" data-row-index="1" src="/Chinese/words/buy.mp3"
        autostart="false"></audio></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Now while I am finding the audio tag whenever I attempt to play it I get the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: sound.play is not a function",
}
```

Testing this on a vanilla HTML page works. So I am guessing that even though I am finding the audio tag it is no longer recognised as audio? Or perhaps the ASPX render engine is getting things messed up because the audio tag has a runat="server".

Can someone help me out in terms of getting this to play>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery` selector returns a `jQuery` object. You need to access the DOM element in order to access WebAudio APIs. You can use [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the DOM element.

```
// use .get(0) to the DOM element.
var sound = $(".audio-file[data-row-index='" + rowIndex + "']").get(0); 
sound.play();
```

```js
function PlaySoundDonoV2(aSelectedImg) {
  var rowIndex = $(aSelectedImg).attr('data-audio-index');
  var sound = $(".audio-file[data-row-index='" + rowIndex + "']").get(0);
  console.log(sound);
  sound.play();
  //Prevent post-back
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="cphContainerWithoutUpdatePanel_gvWordsInLessons" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/kpackage.png" onclick="return PlaySoundDonoV2(this);" data-audio-index="0" />
      <audio class="audio-file" style="display:none;" data-row-index="0" src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/cartoon_boing.ogg" autostart="false"></audio></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/kpackage.png" onclick="return PlaySoundDonoV2(this);" data-audio-index="1" />
      <audio class="audio-file" style="display:none;" data-row-index="1" src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/alarm_clock.ogg" autostart="false"></audio></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```